Displaying CPU and Memory Usage for IIS Application Pools in Grafana
I recently set up Grafana along with Prometheus on my server, using Windows exporter to collect metrics. I have created a panel in Grafana that shows the states of every application pool using the windows_iis_current_application_pool_state metric.

I have also defined a variable $server to allow server selection, enabling me to view the status of application pools in one panel based on the selected server.
Now, I would like to display CPU and memory usage for each IIS application pool within the same panel or new one.
provide an option to filter and choose a specific application pool for detailed monitoring.
How can I achieve this in Grafana using Prometheus metrics?
Thank in advanced
